# ColorResource changes the value with adding other Colors

Tags: android, xml, colors, resources

Something strange happens to my color resource. When I add another color with "card_xy" the resource "card_text" gets another color.

With this resources it works fine:

```
<!-- Cards -->
<color name="card_background">#f7eac8</color>
<color name="card_corner">#8c4646</color>
<color name="card_text">#333232</color>
<color name="card_background_red">#ff432e</color>
<color name="card_background_blue">#008bba</color>
```

But when I add the following resource the 'card_text' gets pink.

```
<color name="card_background_black">#333232</color>
```

I tried other resources aswell. This one works:

```
<color name="test">#FF0000</color>
```

But for example this one doesn't either:

```
<color name="card_black">#FF0000</color>
```

I am really confused. A am currently just adding/removing the 'card_background_black' resource and with every try the color changes.

Comment: Can you add the where are you using those attributes?

Comment: I add the changing-color just like this setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(c, R.color.card_text));

Comment: The new attributes aren't even used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a bug of Android Studio. I woke up today and continued to work. It works fine today.

Should have restarted yesterday.